# Laravel use decoded JSON data as PHP Object

Tags: php, json, laravel

I want to use decoded JSON data as php objects to be able to used as follows:

```
return $data->title
```

however im running into a few errors. I am able to connect to the remote API url and get the requested data.

```
$api        = 'https://remote.api.url/dataset/list';
$json       = file_get_contents($api);
$data       = json_decode($json, true);

dd($data);
```

When i die and dump the data i see the following:

```
array:1 [▼
  "data" => array:5 [▼
    0 => array:5 [▼
      "id" => "qk4GtMb8"
      "title" => "SSA's palliative care has an mHealth deficit "
      "image" => "http://gstatic.acfee.org/akamaihd/i/52fdb957187"
      "published_at" => "2016-06-10 08:05:00"
      "created_at" => array:3 [▼
        "date" => "2016-06-07 05:48:34.000000"
        "timezone_type" => 3
        "timezone" => "UTC"
      ]
    ]
    1 => array:5 [▶]
    2 => array:5 [▶]
    3 => array:5 [▶]
    4 => array:5 [▶]
  ]
]
```

But i am unable to use the recieved data in object form. `return $data->title;`

i am pretty new to JSON any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of **json_decode** (which in your case is true) converts the objects to array. From official PHP docs: *When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.* So if you remove it you should be ok.

Comment: thanks for this. it helped. my final question is i can only return 1 title. in the foreach i have echo $data[0]->title; which works but only returs one. how can i loop through each of them

Comment: @WesMurray why don't you loop all the `$data` instead of only the first one `$data[0]`?

Comment: please see here http://pastebin.com/4ig5H8t5 - but this code seems a bit messy. foreach within a foreach

Comment: @WesMurray if you have array of data that inside has another arrays I don't see another way to access them other than loop inside a loop.